# Get a date from a DatePickerDialog in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

The below snippet of code 'works' in the sense it updates the statusDateID correctly. the issue I am having is that although it sets the statusDateID correctly, the date will not persist, and when I update mh.entryDate it is always the current date.

How do I get the date outside of the dialog. so that I can update mh.entryDate with the chosen date, not the current date.

Thank you for your time.

```
fun changeDate(view: View) {

    var date: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    var thisAYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR).toInt()
    var thisAMonth = date.get(Calendar.MONTH).toInt()
    var thisADay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toInt()

    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view2, thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay ->
        // Display Selected date in textbox
        thisAMonth = thisMonth + 1
        thisADay = thisDay
        thisAYear = thisYear

        statusDateID.setText("Date: " + thisAMonth + "/" + thisDay + "/" + thisYear)
        val newDate:Calendar =Calendar.getInstance()
        newDate.set(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay)

    }, thisAYear, thisAMonth, thisADay)
    dpd.show()

    mh.entryDate = date.timeInMillis
    println("DATE DATA: "+thisAYear+ " "+thisAMonth+" " + thisADay)
    println("DATE CHANGED MILLISECS = "+mh.entryDate)
}
```

mh.entryDate is defined as a global, and as a LONG. With the debugging println statements, both the DATE DATA and the DATE CHANGED MILLISECS show the current date.

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? Like, where is mh defined, and where is the entry date originally defined in there?

Comment: Woogie, I updated the problem statement to answer you question. Put simply mh is a global defined in another module.

Comment: Well that's simply because the two **println** are executed when the DatePicker is shown, and not when you actually change the data

Comment: NSimon, solid observation. With other observations made below, it now works, thank you. (Nothing worse that a bug in your debugging code!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set date inside `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` method with 
`mh.entryDate = newDate.timeInMillis`

```
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view2, thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay ->
    // Display Selected date in textbox
    thisAMonth = thisMonth + 1
    thisADay = thisDay
    thisAYear = thisYear

    statusDateID.setText("Date: " + thisAMonth + "/" + thisDay + "/" + thisYear)
    val newDate:Calendar =Calendar.getInstance()
    newDate.set(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay)
    mh.entryDate = newDate.timeInMillis // setting new date
}, thisAYear, thisAMonth, thisADay)
dpd.show()
```

Comment: That still gives today in milliseconds (1507214431383) even when set to a 2013 date.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, you are correct, once I saw NSimon's comment above I realized that I did not fully understand the mechanism, and the debugging code was invalid.

Comment: @TonySherman I'm glad to help you. You can also upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating the `date` object as a new instance from Calendar, but you are not updating it with the date from the picker. `date` is created, queried, but never updated.

Comment: Great point. I added : date.set(thisAYear, thisAMonth, thisADay), but it was today's date still. Also thisYear, ThisMonth, ThisDay do not exist outside of dpd. but my variables, thisAYear etc, do not seem to keep their values when  I exit the Dialog. They obviously are getting modified as statusDateID is being updated correctly.